# Screen Sharing to multiple Users

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, screen-sharing, client-server

I designed an lms which teacher can run a virtual class.
I need to make a desktop sharing solution (view only) for my project.
As i saw vnc is good but i want to send teacher screen to the server and then broadcast it because it may lots of student and teacher does not have a good bandwidth.
I tested lots of vnc softwares but they are one to one i want to do something like this:

```
                --------------
TEACHER -----> |              | -----> Student
               |     SERVER   |   .
               |              |   .
               |              | -----> Student
                --------------
```

I don't want to use third party websites like join.me , ...
could any body help me with an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [ScreenConnect](http://www.screenconnect.com/Remote-Support-How-It-Works)

Comment: http://openmeetings.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Windows Desktop Sharing API if you want to build something yourself: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2007/03/08/windows-desktop-sharing-api.aspx

Another option is to use web tools and build your own WebRTC-based app: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC

I am not sure about pre-existing software that does this, but these two pieces of info should give you a good start :)

/cd